# Driving in snow, remaining in motion

Tags: energy, kinematics

On days like this in southern Ontario, I always think of a bus ride home from school years ago.

At the start of a trip that stretched to three hours, we came to the ol' steep hill. It was snowing hard and the asphalt was slippery. The bus full of kids began its ascent. Now, this hill was packed with cars crawling along. About two thirds of the way, it became clear that traffic was slowing to a halt.

Making use of the tiny bit of space between the heavy bus and the next car, our driver kept her foot on the gas, as little as possible, in the lowest gear. "The important thing," she said aloud, "is to keep moving, no matter how little. Stop for a split second and you roll all the way to the bottom."

We made it to the top and breathed a sigh of relief. Now I'm wondering: Was she right? If so, what are the physics behind it? What's the magic ingredient in keeping the tiniest bit of forward motion?

Apologies if this is on the wrong StackExchange.

Comment: Alas, vehicular traction is not terribly well represented by simple models of friction, and most physicists (myself among them) are not experts in the matter.

Comment: @dmckee Thanks. Do you know of a better SE for the question, or is it out of scope for the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both when moving (wheels are rolling) and when standing still there is static friction taking place.

There should not be any change in static friction from either situation.

**But** when you try accelerating again after standing still, you are requiring much more force to be exerted on to the asphalt; friction must *increase* so it not only keeps the bus from slipping but also accelerates the bus.

If the static friction can't increase as much as it has to, then it will "let go". The wheels will be slipping and skidding and kinetic friction is taking over because the wheel slides over the asphalt now. And in general, kinetic friction is lower than the static friction maximum. That lower friction may allow the bus to slide downwards.

If the bus wheels ever reach a stationary point again, where they stop sliding, then static friction will take over again and the bus might stop, because that friction is strong enough to hold back. This is the idea behind the ABS antiblocking system in most vehicles, which basically stops the wheel for a split second and hopes to allow it to find a stationary point for regaining static friction.

In the end the conclusion is: It might not be the stopping itself that causes the bus to slide downwards. But starting again after stopping might.

All the above is purely considering friction on even road. The fact that the surface might change along the way (compacting snow and such) will be a complicating extra factor.

Answer (score 2):

I had a used Fiat 1500, 1964 when I was a freshman. Could not afford anything more than absolute necessities, hence the car was in bad state of repairs and tires almost lost all thread to state of being shiny.

I learned by practice exact same thing: if in an uphill road covered by snow you keep the tires rolling, no matter how slow, you probably will make it to the top.
There are some justifications for this:

1- the difference between dynamic and static friction factor.

2- The fact that if for any reason you stop the heat generated by your car my compromise the fragile state of bond between the tires and paving which as an integral component includes the thin sheet of ice!

3- Any sudden acceleration or deceleration will plow through the temporary sandwich of rubber/ice/pavement and start the skidding action!